# what could be the cause of my session keeps changing by itself?

Tags: asp.net

I have a news website , each news had an ID in my database table , I choose 4 IDs randomly to put their titles in the "see more" section .. I select the ID by generating a random row number , the problem is when I click on one of the suggested news it takes me to another news randomly ! which makes no sense to me . the weird thing is the other random ID that I'm taken to does exist but not the one that I clicked.
Latelty I noticed this : for example in the "see more" section we have title1 - title2 - title3 - title4 , so I clicked on title1 it takes me to another random news which i didn't click .. now the 4 titles in the "see more" section are different which is normal .. now when I click in title2 it will take me to the current news in title1 ! and so on next time when i click in title1 it will take me to the curent news in title2 . I can't understand the relation

I tried to store the random numbers in another variables (key1,key2..) before putting one of them in the session but It's still the same problem.
I tried also not refreshing the page (I mean depending just the post back).
I tried clearing the season also tried reomving them all before storing the news Id. There is no error messages.

```
int myrandom1;
int myrandom2;
int myrandom3;
int myrandom4;
string key1;
string key2;
string key3;
string key4;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string key=" ";

        key = Session["key"].ToString();


    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.; initial catalog=celeblogy; integrated security=true");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from news where id like '" + key + "'", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds, "new");

    string Titre = ds.Tables["new"].Rows[0][1].ToString();
    Titre = Titre.Replace("*", "'");
    titre.InnerText = Titre;

    string blog = Decode(ds.Tables["new"].Rows[0][2].ToString());

    string[] Blogs;
            blog = blog.Replace("*", "'");
    Blogs = blog.Split('#');


    Literal1.Text = Blogs[0];
    Image1.Attributes["src"] = "pictures/" + key + "1.jpg";

    if (Blogs.Length >= 2)
    {
        Literal2.Text = Blogs[1];
        Image2.Attributes["src"] = "pictures/" + key + "2.jpg";
    }




    cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from news", con);
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds, "news");

    Random rnd = new Random();


    myrandom1 =rnd.Next(ds.Tables["news"].Rows.Count-1);
    Image3.ImageUrl = "pictures/" + ds.Tables["news"].Rows[myrandom1][0].ToString()+"1.jpg";
    Label1.Text =ds.Tables["news"].Rows[myrandom1][1].ToString().Replace("*","'");
    key1 = ds.Tables["news"].Rows[myrandom1][0].ToString();


    myrandom2 = rnd.Next(ds.Tables["news"].Rows.Count - 1);
    Image4.ImageUrl = "pictures/" + ds.Tables["news"].Rows[myrandom2][0].ToString() + "1.jpg";
    Label2.Text = ds.Tables["news"].Rows[myrandom2][1].ToString().Replace("*", "'");
    key2 = ds.Tables["news"].Rows[myrandom2][0].ToString();

    myrandom3 = rnd.Next(ds.Tables["news"].Rows.Count - 1);
    Image5.ImageUrl = "pictures/" + ds.Tables["news"].Rows[myrandom3][0].ToString() + "1.jpg";
    Label3.Text = ds.Tables["news"].Rows[myrandom3][1].ToString().Replace("*", "'");
    key3 = ds.Tables["news"].Rows[myrandom3][0].ToString();


    myrandom4 = rnd.Next(ds.Tables["news"].Rows.Count - 1);
    Image6.ImageUrl = "pictures/" + ds.Tables["news"].Rows[myrandom4][0].ToString() + "1.jpg";
    Label4.Text = ds.Tables["news"].Rows[myrandom4][1].ToString().Replace("*", "'");
    key4 = ds.Tables["news"].Rows[myrandom4][0].ToString();


}




protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["key"] =key1;
        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
    }

protected void LinkButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["key"] = key2;
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
}

protected void LinkButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["key"] = key3;
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);

}

protected void LinkButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["key"] = key4;
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
}
```

[picture of the see more section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEz2S.png)

Comment: Wrap everything in `Page_Load` inside an `IsPostBack` check.

Comment: still the same problem , lately I noticed this : 
for example in the see more section we have title1 - title2 - title3 - title4 , so I clicked on title1 it takes me to another random news which i didn't click .. now the 4 titles in the "see more" section are different which is normal .. now when I click in title2 it will take me to the current news in title1 ! and so on next time when i click in title1 it will take me to the curent news in title2 . I can't understand the relation

Comment: honestly , this is the most challenging problem in my coding life !